# WPF & Telerik RadTreeView: How do I intercept the ItemSelected event on drag?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik

I have a Telerik RadTreeView.

I am using the ItemSelected event to open a detail view for the selected item.

I am using the Drag and Drop functionality to do as you would expect, rearrange the hierarchy of items in my tree. Nothing special.

The problem comes that when I click to drag the item in my tree, it opens the detail view for that item because the ItemSelected event is fired. Is there a point at which I can tell that an item is being dragged prior to the ItemSelected event being fired so that I can cancel or intercept the ItemSelected event and prevent the detail view from being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The ItemSelected event fires before the DragDropManager can intercept any events, so there's no way to know that the operation you are about to complete is a Drag & Drop operation. Thus using the ItemSelected cannot be utilized here.

However, all is not lost. The ItemClick event only fires on MouseUp and as such, it doesn't fire during a DragDrop operation. Conveniently the DragDropManager handles the event so it doesn't fire on Drop when you let go the mouse button.

So execute your ItemSelected behaviour in the `ItemClick` event (which has the same event signature as ItemSelected, so you can just rename it to keep things semantically correct).

**XAML**

```
<MyTreeView ItemClick="MyTreeView_OnItemClick" />
```

**Codebehind**

```
public class CodeBehind {

    public CodeBehind() {
        var handleDroppedEvents = true;
        DragDropManager.AddDropHandler(MyTreeView, MyTreeView_OnDropCompleted, handleDroppedEvents);
        DragDropManager.AddDragDropCompletedHandler(MyTreeView, MyTreeView_OnDragDropCompleted, handleDroppedEvents);
    }

    private void MyTreeView_OnItemClick(object sender, RadRoutedEventArgs e) {
       var tree = (RadTreeView) sender;
       ....
    }

    private void MyTreeView_OnDropCompleted(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        /* If you want to suppress the default drop behaviour 
         * e.g. moving items around your tree */
        var options =
            DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, TreeViewDragDropOptions.Key) as TreeViewDragDropOptions;

        if (options == null)
            return;

        /* Tell Telerik not to do its default thing */
        options.DropAction = DropAction.None;
    }

    private void MyTreeView_OnDragDropCompleted(object sender DragDropCompletedEventArgs e) {
       ....
    }

}
```

Now your ItemSelected process will to the user to appear to trigger on select, but the selection will be intercepted and replaced with the drag/drop functionality if you drag.